# Synthesis of cycloserine: What is the mechanism of this step?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I want to know the mechanism or some explanation as to how the last step here (with hydroxylamine) works:

> [image]

Comment: But why for example hydroxylamine doesn`t attack chlorine as nucleophillic substitution to give OH group back there? It would make much more sense as chlorine seems to be more reactive then some ester bond. @Waylander

Comment: I can't definitively answer that except to observe that the major product is the hydroxamic acid. What I don't know is what the yield of this reaction is, attack on the chloromethyl could be a byproduct.

Comment: C-Cl bond is strong, chloride is poor leaving group - these are factors that may contribute to its relative lack of reactivity under these conditions. Obviously, these are only back-rationalisations.

Answer (score 2):

The hydroxylamine attacks the methyl ester through nitrogen giving the intermediate hydroxamic acid. The oxygen to the hydroxamic acid then attacks the chloromethyl to displace chlorine giving cycloserine.